# discord.py: Can you get the name of a user that's not in a server with your bot from their id?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have seen discord bots that have the ability to get info(like the name) of users from their id that aren't even in any servers with that bot, and I was wondering if this is possible in discord.py.  I know about

```
client.get_user(id)
```

but if the user isn't in any servers with the bot it won't work.  Can you do this in discord.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the API call [fetch_user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user)

```
user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
```

Stick to that link (official documentation) and you won't be wasting time on trivial setbacks like this.

Comment: Thanks! I had looked at the API before but never saw that.